# Can Travis-CI test diff instead of all files?

Tags: git, github, travis-ci

We would like to improve our code quality, but we’re working on legacy code and using Travis-CI now would trigger lots of changes that the team won’t be able to handle.

To improve code step by step, I was wondering if there is *a way to check only modified files*, or **even better: just the modified lines**.

We could get rid of inconsistencies as we code and switch to “all code coverage” once we feel we have the time for it.

Answer (score 6):

Travis-CI runs on a Git repository with the code checked-out. You can teach your test scripts to run `git diff --name-only HEAD^` to get the modified files, and then run only the tests corresponding to them.

Comment: Thanks a lot Matthieu, I’ll check that out and update here with the status. Hopefully tomorrow or after tomorrow.

Comment: Didn’t manage to get `git diff --name-only HEAD^` to work properly for now, unfortunately.

Comment: Does this work on multi-commit pull requests?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. But you can walk through commits in the pull-request using `git rev-list $TRAVIS_BRANCH..HEAD` (commits in `HEAD` but not present in the target branch). Probably someone already wrote a script doing this...